# Enabling cancellationToken on NET6 Lambda (REST API Gateway)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, .net-6.0, cancellation-token

We have a REST (edge) API Gateway to invoke a .NET 6 lambda function and in which we have included CancellationToken in some endpoints. It seems CancellationToken does not get propagated, and we are not sure what we are missing.

Has anyone else faced this issue and could provide us some insights?

Thanks